# how to calculate “3day_before_change” in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file with historical data for a company. It contains: open price, close price, volume, etc. But I need to add the column “3day_before_change” to the file, in which for each record there should be the ratio of the closing price of the current record to the closing price of the record 3 days ago.

If i had all dates, probably it would be easy task to do in cycle. But some dates are missing, and that’s stops me. Maybe there some tool to perform such tasks ?

At the end it should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ortniter welcome on SO. Please consider to read [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular share date code as text no picture.

Comment: I added the `pandas` tag and removed `csv` as this is a pandas question.

Comment: @rpanai what if someone propose a raw python/csv solution?

Comment: @marmeladze I added back, I don't think it will be an ideal solution but you are right.

Comment: Did any of the answers answer you? if so, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/694919)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can expande your DF using `reindex` day by day, calc '3_day_change' using `.shift()` and drop all rows where **close** are null

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='D'))
df['3day_before_change'] = df['close'] / df['close'].shift(3)
df.loc[df['close'].notnull()]
```

in theory it should work with the data in the image, but I couldn't reproduce the answer because your data is not in text format

Answer (score 0):

This actually works in native python:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import datetime, csv
    
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'

source = open(***<<your cvs name>>***,'r').read()
header = source.split('\n')[0].split('\t') # \t as a delimiter in your csv. Could be ',' or whatever else you have

data = OrderedDict()

# prepare the dictionary
for head in header:    
    data[head] = []
    
# add desired column
data['3day_before_change'] = []

# fill the dictionary with values
for i, line in enumerate(reversed(source.split('\n')[1:])):
    for idx, line_data in enumerate(line.split('\t')):        
        list(data.items())[idx][1].append(line_data)
    
    list(data.items())[idx+1][1].append('-')
       
    # check if there's a '3 day before' value, add the ratio
    curDay = datetime.datetime.strptime(list(data.items())[0][1][-1], date_format)
    threeDays_before = curDay - datetime.timedelta(days=3)    
    
    if threeDays_before.strftime(date_format) in list(data.items())[0][1]:
        curVal = eval(data['Close*'][i])
        threeDayVal = eval(data['Close*'][list(data.items())[0][1].index(threeDays_before.strftime(date_format))])
        
        data['3day_before_change'][i] = curVal/threeDayVal

l=[]
for lst in data.values():
    l.append(lst)
l=zip(*l)
l=reversed(list(l))

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")
    writer.writerow(data.keys())
    for line in l:
        writer.writerow(line)
```